# Not able to iterate a Javascript Set in stackblitz?

Tags: javascript, loops, set, stackblitz

I'm trying to iterate a Javascript Set in Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/javascript-set-iterate?file=index.js

```
for (const n of s) {
  array.push(n);
  console.log(n);
}
```

However the for loop has never been entered somehow.

When I opened the Source tab in Chrome Dev Tools and I saw it's translated as:

```
for (var _i = 0, s_1 = s; _i < s_1.length; _i++) {
    var n = s_1[_i];
    array.push(n);
    console.log(n);
}
```

Apparently there is no **length** property for Set in Javascript. It should be **size**:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set So the loop is skipped by mistake.

If I run the same `for...of` code in the browser console it works fine.

**Question:**

I'm not sure whether it's my Stackblitz configuration wrong (compiler selection of ES5/ES6 etc.?) or it's a Stackblitz bug?

Thanks!

Comment: It should've been `s_1 = Array.from(s)`. Probably a bug

Comment: This sounds like indeed there's something wrong with the transpilation settings (e.g. the [`assumeArray` flag being set](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-for-of#assumearray)), but I don't know where to change that in Stackblitz.